# Check if a template argument is a std::vector<T>::iterator

Tags: c++, templates, vector, iterator

How to check if a template argument is a `std::vector<T>::iterator`?

For void type, we have std::is_void. Is there something like that for `std::vector<T>::iterator`?

Comment: @W.F. The `<T>` didn't show up before I add . Sorry for that. I was thinking about writing custom traits. Like `template <template <typename T> std::vector<T> class> struct is_vec_iterator { static const bool value = true; };`

Comment: I don't believe you can, but you can check if the argument is a Random Access Iterator.

Comment: i think the whole point of templates is to not get specific. use template specialization if you need special implementation for a specific type

Comment: @dotdotdot which standard of C++ are you aiming for?

Comment: @krzaq C++11 or C++14.

Comment: Roughly you can take it as `VecIt` and then verify that `typename std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<VecIt>::value_type>::iterator` and `VecIt` name the same type, but that doesn't guarantee that the thing you got is actually an iterator into a vector, so it's not that useful.

Comment: What's the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: The standard allows for `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be `T*`. That could give you lots of false positives for any tests you design.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a trait for that:

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <type_traits>


template <class T, class = void>
struct is_vector_iterator: std::is_same<T, std::vector<bool>::iterator> { };

template <class T>
struct is_vector_iterator<T, decltype(*std::declval<T>(), std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<T, std::vector<bool>::iterator>::value>())>: std::is_same<T, typename std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>>::iterator> { };

int main() {
    static_assert(is_vector_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>::value, "Is not a vector iterator");
    static_assert(is_vector_iterator<std::vector<bool>::iterator>::value, "Is not a vector iterator");
    static_assert(!is_vector_iterator<std::list<int>::iterator>::value, "Is a vector iterator");
    static_assert(!is_vector_iterator<std::list<int>::iterator>::value, "Is a vector iterator");
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/5MT0vGDCP7magrKH)

Comment: Gives true for `is_vector_iterator<std::list<int>::iterator>`.

Comment: Fails for `std::vector<bool>::iterator` ;)

Comment: @W.F. why are you using `std::decay_t<decltype(*std::declval<T>())>` instead of just `T::value_type`?

Comment: @ComeRaczy as far as I know vector iterator is implementation dependent and as such it does not have to contain `value_type` included (as Bo Persson suggested it is even allowed it to be defined as pointer to contained type)...

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution also using *std::iterator_traits*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
struct is_vector_iterator 
{
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no[2];

    template <typename C>
    static yes& test(
        typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_same<T, typename std::vector<typename C::value_type>::iterator>::value
        >::type*);

    template <typename>
    static no& test(...);

    static const bool value = sizeof(test<T>(nullptr)) == sizeof(yes);

};

int main() {
    std::cout << is_vector_iterator<int>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_vector_iterator<int*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_vector_iterator<std::list<int>::iterator>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << is_vector_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1710de9c311f080)

Comment: Unfortunately, it will also be true for `std::list<int>::iterator`. The purpose is to determine if it's a `std::vector<T>::iterator` or not. Not just an iterator.

Comment: I fixed it now!

Comment: So you think: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e5b2e165bd94081)

Comment: I guess I finally fixed it now. I definitely learned something... and my example is quite similar to yours now anyway.

Comment: I didn't know that std::iterator_traits had a specialization for raw pointers!

Answer (score 3):

Better using [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits) I think:

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template <class It, class = void>
struct is_vector_iterator : std::false_type { };

template <class It>
struct is_vector_iterator<It, std::enable_if_t<
                                  std::is_same<
                                      It,
                                      typename std::vector< 
                                          typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type
                                      >::iterator
                                  >::value
                         >> : std::true_type { };

int main() {
    static_assert(is_vector_iterator<std::vector<int>::iterator>::value, "Is not a vector iterator");
    static_assert(is_vector_iterator<std::vector<bool>::iterator>::value, "Is not a vector iterator");
    static_assert(!is_vector_iterator<std::list<int>::iterator>::value, "Is a vector iterator");
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e8f4d295ba900a41)

Comment: why use `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type` instead of `It::value_type`?

Comment: Because as said **Bo Persson** above: *The standard allows for `std::vector<T>::iterator` to be `T*`* and a pointer doesn't have a `value_type` member.

Comment: @ComeRaczy Also, to handle the case with `bool` where `*std::declval<It>()` is not a `bool&` but a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a trait for this:

```
namespace detail
{

template<typename T> constexpr std::false_type is_vector_iterator(T&&, ...)
{
    return {};
}

template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_vector_iterator(T&& t, void* = nullptr) ->
decltype(std::is_same<typename std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(*t)>>::iterator, std::decay_t<T>>{})
{
    return {};
}

}

template<typename T>
struct is_vector_iterator : decltype(detail::is_vector_iterator(declval<T>(), 0)) {};
```

Here I'm getting the decayed type of  *t to make `vector<type>::iterator` and check that for equality with `T`. It works with the exception of `vector<bool>` which isn't really a vector anyway.

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vqCvdYS8ItSZAbGA)